# How to handle null pointer exception in wicket form submit

Tags: java, html, wicket

I have two textboxes and one submit button in my program.when i provide some inputs and hit the submit button it works fine. When am not entering anything in the textboxes and hit the submit button , it is not working. It throwed the null pointer exception when form submit.

Error is below.

```
WicketMessage: Method onFormSubmitted of interface org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.IFormSubmitListener targeted at component [MarkupContainer [Component id = form1]] threw an exception

    Root cause:

    java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.usaa.application.pages.HomePage$3.onSubmit(HomePage.java:158)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.delegateSubmit(Form.java:1518)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.process(Form.java:914)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.onFormSubmitted(Form.java:876)
```

How to handle this error , please help me ...

Thanks,
Kumar

Comment: Check whatever you do in your HomePage.java:158 and make sure you don't get a NPE.

Comment: Catch the null value in your code? Fix the line 158 that is mentioned in your error.

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
Textfield<String> tf1 = new TextField<String>("tf1");
tf1.setConvertEmptyInputStringToNull(false);
form.add(tf1);
```

The value from the textfield is now an empty string

Comment: That worked .... after i have added the setconvertemptyinputstringtonull method.

Comment: Same issue here, this method did nothing for me.